# How to pass IJSObjectReference to JS code as argument

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, interop

I've already read that I can invoke JS methods on `IJSObjectReference` but how to pass such object to JS code as an argument?

Let' say I have such JS code:

```
    addLayer: function (group,layer) {
      ...
```

In C# I have two references `IJSObjectReference` for both "group" and "layer", how do I pass them to such function?

---

Obtaining JS reference, example.

```
    createGroup: function () {
        var js_group = L.markerClusterGroup();
        return js_group;
    },
```

and C# call:

```
var js_ref = await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>($"{MarkerClusterInterop.BaseObjectContainer}.createGroup").ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Can you share more code? How do you obtain those `IJSObjectReference`s that you are talking about?

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos, I added the section with example for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invoke `addLayer` function using `IJSRuntime` and pass the `IJSObjectReference`s as parameters after the function identifier.

```
@inject IJSRuntime JS

@code {
    private IJSObjectReference _groupJSObjectRef;
    private IJSObjectReference _layerJSObjectRef;

    ...

    private async Task SomeMethodAsync()
    {
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync($"{MarkerClusterInterop.BaseObjectContainer}.addLayer", _groupJSObjectRef, _layerJSObjectRef);
    }
}
```

Comment: One stupid mistake on my part and I already thought I need some extra magic.Thank you for pointing out "obvious" way :-).